Does a fabric that can wick up pure water from salt water exist?
Does a fabric that can wick up pure water from salt water exist?
The inspiration is semipermeable membranes (such as the U-tube experiments).
Given size differences between H2O molecules and Na, Cl atoms, I am assuming that theoretically there can exist a wicking fabric that uses capillary action (not evaporation) to bring up water molecules only from a salt-water solution.
Alternatively, I hypothesize electrets can be used to exclude pure ions while still allowing polar molecules up some fiber.
(Interestingly, I got different answers from ChatGPT and Perplexity.ai: ChatGPT says they exist, and Perplexity says they don't).

And that's the reason you shouldn't trust AI.

Reverse osmosis needs pressure. From cursory search, at least 2 bar, even for fresh water. The higher the osmotic pressure of solution the more external pressure is needed to overcome it. Capillary forces are too weak to have significant effect. (And best not even mention artificial stupidity around here.)

@NilayGhosh Fair point, but you must admit that the "Artificial Stupidity" filters away low quality questions from Stack Exchange, and that it is more efficient than browsing for papers using a search engine, no?

@Mithoron I see. I did see some papers mentioning electrets and their potential in desalination, what are your thoughts on this?

Except it's us who filter away low quality questions from Stack Exchange. AI simply cannot tell bullshit from valuable information.

Materials that can do this already exist: Sodium polyacrylate, the plastic used to make Orbeez, quite obviously has sodium ions contained within its molecular lattice, which have a positive charge.
This makes it highly attractive to water; when the two come into contact, the water molecules begin to infiltrate the plastic, causing it to expand.
This can absorb water from salt solutions but the mechanism gives it one drawback: as sodium polyacrylate relies on essentially being 'salty' to absorb, it is at its most effective in pure water, gradually becoming worse at absorbing as the dissolved ion content of the solution increases, until the ion concentration of the plastic and solution are equal, at which point it can't absorb at all; beyond this point, the solution will actually start to remove water from the plastic instead.

That is a great insight! So you are essentially saying for brine, sodium polyacrylate (ACR) would just need to contain more sodium ions?

In addition, would the ACR contain pure water, or in a brine solution would it also absorb NaCl?
